# How to determine the number of solutions of a function?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

From a mathematical point of view, how do you determine the number of solution of a function?

---

I'll explain:

If I have a generic equation with a function (not considering polynomials):

$$f(x)=c$$

Depending on the type of function I can have multiple results:

**$f(x)$ is a direct function**

$$e^x=c \ \Rightarrow \ x=\ln(c)+2k\pi i \qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\sin(x)=c\ \Rightarrow \ x=2\pi k+\pi-\arcsin(c), x=2k\pi+\arcsin(c)\qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$x e^x=c\ \Rightarrow \ x=W_{k}(x)\qquad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

*In this case the equation has an infinite number of solutions*

**$f(x)$ is an inverse function**

$$\ln(x)=c \ \Rightarrow \ x=e^c$$
$$\arcsin(x)=c\ \Rightarrow \ x=\sin(c)$$
$$W(x)=c\ \Rightarrow \ x=c e^c$$

*In this case the equation has only 1 solution*

---

Therefore given a generic function
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

How can I determine if the equation
$$f(x)=c$$

has 1 or infinite solutions?

> I don't know if it's a trivial question, but it doesn't seem obvious to me. I know that for example the logarithm is defined as the inverse function of the exponential, but if I started by first defining the logarithm as the derivative of $1/x$ I would go so far as to say that the exponential is its inverse.

Comment: Those concepts are relative. There is no such thing as an "absolute direct function". If you consider the log to be your direct function, then its inverse is the exponential, or viceversa. These functions are inverse of each other.

Comment: @GReyes I know, but I noticed this thing that the functions defined as "inverse" have only 1 solution, while the "direct" ones (pass me the term) have infinite ones. I wanted to understand what changed since the concept of inverse function is relative, there must be some property that escapes me.

Comment: When you consider a function, would you also specify its domain and codomain? Like for $e^x:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, it's injective.

Comment: @peterwhy I don't know if it's a fundamental aspect to determine it, can't it be understood given the series of the function? (In this case I consider a totally random function like $0.2+\pi x-ex^2+\phi x^5+e^{-3}x^6+...$)

Comment: You can find inverse functions of general functions defined over a small neighborhood of a point via the inverse function theorem, but globally defined inverses require more work or more restrictive properties.

Comment: In robotics, there are several kinematic problems I run into where the direct kinematics or inverse kinematics solutions have multiple or infinetly many solutions (the relation between motor angles and end effector position), so, complicated.

Comment: I think this is a byproduct of the way inverse functions are usually defined. A function needs to be one-to-one to be invertible, so we restrict the domain of the "direct" function until we have a one-to-one function, then we invert that function and get another one-to-one function. If you restrict the "direct" function to the domain you use when defining its inverse, I think you'll find all solutions are unique.

Comment: So $f(x)=c$ has a unique solution $x$ for every $c$ in the range of $f$ if and only if $f$ is one-to-one. Is there a practical method to deduce that property from a series? Don't forget to consider the domain of the function; $f(x)=e^x$ is one-to-one if the domain is the real numbers.

Comment: (1) I don't think your use of the term "direct function" is standard (I certainly have no idea what you mean by it). (2) Given a function defined by a power series $\sum a_n x^n$, there is very little you can say about the number of its zeroes without a lot more specific information about the coefficients $a_n$.